# Resume views count

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

On the old careers page, I was able to see the number of views of my CV, organized in a few separate sections: public views, employer views, ...

Is this feature still available now with the careers being part of the main Stack Overflow jobs?

Comment: It's fine marking it as duplicate. However, I guess there are many others missing that small piece of functionality, as far as I see.